# How to show special escape characters like LineBreak in Java output?

Tags: java, string, character

Cannot find a solution to seem to be a simple question. For example, I have a string with LineBreak ”a\na”.  The System.out.println output of this string shows 2 lines.  However, I need to show the output in exactly the same form, i.e. “a\na”.    How to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape your `\n` with an extra backslash..

Use: - `"a\\na"` to get `\n` in your output..

```
System.out.println("a\\na"); // Prints a\na
```

Or, you can also take a look at :- [`Apache Commons`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) [`StringEscapeUtils#escapeJava`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava%28java.lang.String%29) which will automatically excape all the special `escape sequences` with an extra backslash..

```
String str = "a\nb\r\t";
String result = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(str); // Takes `\n` as `\\n`
System.out.println(result);
```

This will print: - `a\nb\r\t`

Comment: Sure, but what about the general case, where you don't know in advance where the `\n` and other special characters are? Isn't that what the question is about?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Well, OP just posted a specific String, and didn't say anything about generality.

Comment: In that case the question should be closed as a duplicate rather than answered for the millionth time on SO. But I don't think the OP's actual problem is printing the specific string `a\na`; that was just an example.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett. Yeah that's right. Updated my post. :)

Comment: I agree with Jean-François Corbett that the 1st version of the answer (to escape \n) did not provide the solution. My question was about displaying an already created string.  However, the second version suggesting using StringEscapeUtils was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @anarinsky Yeah that is why I edited the post. You're welcome :)

Comment: I hope both of you upvoted Matt Whipple's answer which was the first to link to `StringEscapeUtils`, apparently inspiring this answer!

Answer (score 4):

For a general purpose solution you could look at something like [StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) from Apache Commons

Comment: Yes, the only thing is that you have \n on your string. Not a big drama.