# Bulk Insert - Incorrect syntax near ' '. in SQL Server 2008

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using Java code to insert a data in SQL Server 2008. I am getting below error.

```
    Statement st = null;
    Connection con = null;
    String loadQuery = "";
    Class.forName(com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver);
    con =              DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc:sqlserver://11.11.112.123:1433;DatabaseName=test123, test, test);
   st = con.createStatement();
 loadQuery = "BULK INSERT testres FROM  'D:\RTTM\NTB\Data\GDW\Files\ACCif.csv' WITH ( FIRSTROW=2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')";
 System.out.println(loadQuery);
st.executeUpdate(loadQuery);
```

**Query**

```
BULK INSERT testres FROM  'D:\RTTM\NTB\Data\GDW\Files\ACCif.csv' WITH ( FIRSTROW=2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

**Error**

```
Incorrect syntax near ' '.

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ' '.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1493)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:775)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:676)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4874)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:179)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:154)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerStatement.java:633)
    at QueryCreation_sqlserver.readCsvUsingLoad(QueryCreation_sqlserver.java:225)
    at QueryCreation_sqlserver.readCsvcoloumnname(QueryCreation_sqlserver.java:268)
    at QueryCreation_sqlserver.main(QueryCreation_sqlserver.java:39)
Incorrect syntax near ' '.
```

**Database Details**

```
Driver name: Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 3.0
Driver version: 3.0.1119.0
Product name: Microsoft SQL Server
Product version: 10.50.1600
```

**JDBC jar Details**

```
sqljdbc4-3.0.jar
```

Comment: does this query work when you run it using an SQL Server client like SQL Studio Management Studio. I think there is a problem with the query syntax and nothing to with the Java code or Driver.

Comment: same query working in SQL Studio Management

Comment: In that case it is likely that your java code is not creating the query correctly. Have you tried printing the query just before you call the execute method in java.

Comment: BULK INSERT RTTM_Fixed_Fields_data_tbl_14_177_S FROM  'C:\Projects\Netbank_Fixed_Fields.csv' WITH ( FIRSTROW=2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' )

Comment: have you [escaped](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) your \ backslash?

Comment: u r asking to use double slash \\ for single slash \?

Comment: @cha as he said the query which is printed, works on SQL Server, so this should not be the question.

Comment: it is not working in java

Comment: [edit] your question and add the Java code that runs the query

Comment: Could you remove one of the spaces after FROM and try again?

Comment: I tryed. no luck mate

Comment: In a Java `String` the backslash needs to be doubled: `"BULK INSERT testres FROM  'D:\\RTTM\\NTB\\Data\\GDW\\Files\\ACCif.csv'`.

Comment: This is a silly one but I had this happened to me once: check that your table and DB name do not have a trailing space. SSMS allows you to create objects with trailing spaces e.g. [blah ], or rather it is much easier to make that mistake when using GUI

Answer (score 0):

Can you escape back slashes in `D:\RTTM\NTB\Data\GDW\Files\ACCif.csv`?

Comment: Yes -  D:\\RTTM\\NTB\\Data\\GDW\\Files\\ACCif.csv

Answer (score 0):

```
loadQuery = "BULK INSERT testres FROM  'D:\RTTM\NTB\Data\GDW\Files\ACCif.csv' WITH ( FIRSTROW=2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')";
```

The above statements has a lot of backslashes and as you would know the '\' in a java string is used to indicate start of an escape sequence. 
When the loadQuery variable is used internally it will result in a broken sql being fired. 
So your can do below

```
loadQuery = "BULK INSERT testres FROM  'D:\\RTTM\\NTB\\Data\\GDW\\Files\\ACCif.csv' WITH ( FIRSTROW=2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n')";
```

From the syntax error suggested in stack trace i suspect that most likely the query breaks at the '\n' character being presented to the SQL interpreter as a SQL string ' ' spread over two lines rather than your original intent of sending it as '\n'

You should also have a look at this question [How to show special escape characters like LineBreak in Java output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882219/how-to-show-special-escape-characters-like-linebreak-in-java-output)

Comment: @Jay Just to confirm when you run this query through your java program against SQL server 2008 it does not run, but without changing any other settings it runs against SQL server 2014 ? That's weird. Could indicate 
Compatibility issues between SQL server versions / syntax across versions

Comment: @ws I am confused about SQL server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2014 as well. Jay, please clarify on which version it is running / not running and whether it was tested from Java / SSMS?